# Passport-jwt token get error messages from server

Tags: express, passport.js, passport-local

I simply cannot figure out how to pass error messages from server to client. I searched the docs, but cannot get where should I implement the callback function to return the error message.

My server-side code looks like this:

passport.js

```
var localLogin = new LocalStrategy(localOptions, function(email, password, done){

User.findOne({
  email: email
 }, function(err, user, info){

if(err){
  return done(err);
}

if(!user){
  return done(null, false, {message: 'User not found'});
}

user.comparePassword(password, function(err, isMatch){

  if(err){
    return done(err);
  }

  if(!isMatch){
    return done(null, false, {message: 'Passwords does not match'});
  }

  return done(null, user);

});

});

});
```

router.js

```
> var requireAuth = passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}),
>     requireLogin = passport.authenticate('local', {session: false});
> 
> module.exports = function(app){
> 
>   var apiRoutes = express.Router(),
>       authRoutes = express.Router(),
>       todoRoutes = express.Router();
> 
>   // Auth Routes   apiRoutes.use('/auth', authRoutes);
> 
>   authRoutes.post('/register', AuthenticationController.register);  
> authRoutes.post('/login', requireLogin, AuthenticationController.login);
```

In the client I receive this error message.

```
Response {_body: "Unauthorized", status: 401, ok: false, statusText: "Unauthorized", headers: Headers…}headers: Headersok: falsestatus: 401statusText: "Unauthorized"type: 2url: "http://localhost:8083/api/auth/login"_body: "Unauthorized"__proto__: Body
```

Comment: the first parameter to the `done` function is an error, just like you did with `if(err) done(err, null)`

Comment: @nadavvadan If I put anything there. I will receive error 500. For the time being I always show  user that his password or email is wrong, even though I do not know which one actually is . :D

Comment: This is actually a feature! not showing why the login failed can protect against `user enumeration` (AKA letting a potential attacker know this email is registered with your system).

Basically you'd want to `catch` the error somewhere and return the bug to the user there.